# Karate 1.3.0.RC1 - Could not find netty-resolver-dns-native-macos-4.1.66.Final-osx-aarch_64.jar

Tags: netty, karate

Has anyone tried migrating their karate application to use the 1.3.0 version? I tried migrating to 1.3.0.RC1 but I'm encountering this error when I build:

```
Could not find netty-resolver-dns-native-macos-4.1.66.Final-osx-aarch_64.jar (io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:4.1.66.Final).
```

Searched in the following locations:
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-resolver-dns-native-macos/4.1.66.Final/netty-resolver-dns-native-macos-4.1.66.Final-osx-aarch_64.jar

if I use the version 1.2.0, it builds fine and actually, my issue with 1.2.0 is the multi threaded bug which is said to be fixed in 1.3.0, which is why I want to try the new version.

NOTE: We're currently using 0.9.6 karate.

Comment: you can try depend on the netty library directly, but yes there could be issues in the way libraries are resolved. please try to contribute a fix if possible

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else encounters this issue, here's how I solved this. the netty-resolver issue is related to the org.springframework.boot gradle plugins. upgrade it and then for 2.x.x or higher versions, will in turn require you to upgrade your gradle version to 6.8 or up. After you upgrade both, this error will disappear.